# How can I visualise points on a single line in R?

Tags: r, plot, visualization, line-plot

I'm wanting to plot 3 numerical size values on one line in R in order of ascending size, but research so far has pointed me towards regular line graphs. I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

where size increases from left to right and I can plot my 3 data points on the line to show where each sample falls. It doesnt need to be as complicated as this example, just one line standalone.
How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Check out https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/lollipop-plot.html

Comment: @Emy This is perfect- The one I need is the Cleveland dot plots, but with 3 points. Is it possible to amend it like that?

Comment: sorry I am not an expert in ggplot. I recommend that you start building a Cleveland dot plot with a small dataset that is similar to what you have, then if you run into an issue you can post a minimal reproducible example, and I am sure people will help you https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-how-to-do-a-minimal-reproducible-example-reprex-for-beginners/23061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick recreation:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear = as.factor(gear)) %>%
  summarize(min = min(wt),
            max = max(wt),
            mean = mean(wt),
            sd = sd(wt),
            median = median(wt)) -> summary


ggplot(summary, aes(y=gear)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = min, xmax = max), height = 0.04, color = "gray70") +
  geom_segment(aes(yend = gear, x = mean-sd, xend = mean+sd), alpha = 0.3, 
               color = "forestgreen", size = 10) +
  geom_point(aes(x = median), shape = 17, color = "darkred") +
  geom_text(aes(x = median, label = median), vjust = -1.5) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Ah this is perfect! How could I modify this to have 3 points? So basically I have 3 numbers representing size, lets say 1, 4, and 10. I would want the first point of one line at 1, another at 4 and one at 10. I dont need the mean or median or anything, so I'm not sure how to implement it whilst ignoring that? Thanks so much

Comment: Just add more `geom_point` layers, I guess. I'm not sure I understand. I'd refer you here if you're interested in learning more about ggplot2, which is a fantastic R package for data visualization.  https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go. I'll ask again if I get stuck :)